# Convert String Variable into Function

Tags: powershell

I spitted the steps of my setup script into different functions. I want to be able to stop the script sometime. If I restart the script it should continue the last step where I stopped. So I logged the last step in a Tempfile. If I start the script it reads the tempfiles last logged step and jumps to that step on restart.

```
Function Step1 {
Set-Content -Path $TEMPFILE -value "Step1" #"Setting current step" into a temp file

do first stuff #part in th function. e.g. copy files, add access rights...

Step2 #calling the next function
}

Function Step2 {
Set-Content -Path $TEMPFILE -value "Step2"

do second stuff 

Step3...  
}

...Step 25
```

On Startup the script checks if a Tempfile is existing and add the last step into a variable[String]

Is there any way to get this String Variable into a "Jump To Function" Sequence?
like:...

```
If ($GETSTEP){
   Write-Host "Continuing with $GETSTEP"
   $GOTO = ${function:GETSTEP}
   &GOTO
   }else{
   Write-Host "GET STARTET"
   Step1
   }
```

PowerShell version 5.1.14393.3471 ...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `$GETSTEP` contains the script as a string:

```
if($GETSTEP){
  # Use ScriptBlock.Create() to create a scriptblock from a string
  $scriptBlock = [scriptblock]::Create($GETSTEP)
  &$scriptBlock
}
```

---

If `$GETSTEP` contains the *name* of a function to execute, then it's much simpler - use the call operator (`&`) to invoke the function:

```
if($GETSTEP){
    & $GETSTEP
}
```

Comment: And you can say `$function:myfunc = $scriptblock`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But in ´$GETSTEP´ will be the NAME of the  next Function.

Comment: @oberpiller much simpler then, just do `& $GETSTEP` then

Answer (score 2):

This will create the function getstep:

```
$function:getstep = [scriptblock]::Create($GETSTEP)
```